# Upgrade online game client on iOS when protocols have changed

Tags: mobile, upgrade

We are currently running an online game on iOS, and recently we made some changes both on the client and on the server, which leads to some protocol changes. We realized that if we submit the app to App Store to do the approval, they should connect to our new server. So we should deploy our new server for them to test. However, if we deploy our new server, all the players currently playing our game cannot connect to our server until the app pass the test.

How is this kind of problem usually be solved?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have this problem at one time or another anyway, since you probably cannot expect everyone to immediately upgrade to the new version once it is released.

You could solve this by creating a new endpoint at the server for the new version of the game, still keeping the old one around for those that have the older version of the game.